# Cucumber tests - browser detects bot user agent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I need to test some behavior on cucumber with both "bot" and "user" user-agent.

In some controllers, I have a bot guard clause

```
if browser.bot?
  redirect_to(canonical_path, status: :moved_permanently) 
else
  do_some_tracking
  redirect_somewhere
end
```

I have a cucumber test with features that can vary according to whether a bot or a user visits the page

```
Feature: Visit the special page

  Scenario: A bot visits the special page
    When I visit the special page
    I should see the home page

  Scenario: A user visits the special page not signed in
    Given I am not logged-in
    When I visit the special page
    I should see "Who are you ?"

  Scenario: A user visits the special page signed in
    Given I am logged-in as "michael"
    When I visit the special page
    I should see "Achievement earned : explorer"
```

Is there a way to modify the user agent on a per-scenario basis ?

I though of using tags and `Before`/`After` blocks in `env.rb` But I'm not sure how to actually change the user-agent string of the current driver (and revert it back to normal afterwards)

*Otherwise the default Poltergeist driver's user-agent is "PhantomJS" which is always recognized as a bot for the `browser` gem*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Poltergeist (since it's mentioned in your question) You can override the user-agent for the current test by setting the 'User-Agent' header in a tag based Before block (it will automatically get reset at the next test).

```
page.driver.add_header("User-Agent", "whatever you want")
```

This is documented in the Poltergeist README - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#manipulating-request-headers

If you're not using Poltergeist the other drivers also have ways of setting headers, and there is a `capybara-user_agent` gem that provides a uniform API for setting the user-agent.  The gem hasn't been updated in a while though so I don't know whether it still works or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the gem ! I also wasn't sure it was possible to just call `page` in a before tag but it works just fine.

Comment: Oh well, as you said the gem is quite old and doesn't seem to works with Selenium anymore...